# Code correctly copies multiple rows from one table to another, but ignores single records in the source table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have multiple tables with varying line items relating to different products. I need to copy the items relating to a selected product into equivalent front end tables. This works fine if there are multiple line items relating to the product in the source table, but single line items don't get copied.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    RecordRows = Application.CountIf(DBTable2(i).ListColumns(IDColumn.Index).Range, IDCurrent)
    b = 1
    d = Application.Match(IDCurrent, DBTable2(i).ListColumns(IDColumn.Index).Range, 0) - 1
    For rw = 1 To RecordRows
        InputTable2(i).ListRows(b).Range.Value = DBTable2(i).ListRows(d).Range.Value
        InputTable2(i).DataBodyRange(b, 1).Range.FormulaR1C1 = "=CU_ID"
        b = b + 1
        d = d + 1
    Next rw
```

Parameter i, b and d identify the correct records.

Comment: Do you know how to use the VBA debugger? Put a break point, examine variables, step through the code...?

Comment: I printed out i, b and d and it cycles through correctly and identifies the correct values. For some reason I can't step through with F8. After some point it just jumps to the end, even though the subsequent code is executed correctly.

Comment: If variable  `d` is 0 then you get an error. Can it occur?

Comment: It wasn't the case in the tests I ran.

Comment: It must be jumping to the end because of an error.

Answer (score 0):

### Copying Sorted Data From One Excel Table to Another

```
Sub Test()
    
    Const DST_FORMULA_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const DST_FORMULA_R1C1 As String = "=CU_ID" 
    
    Dim DBTable2() As ListObject, InputTable2() As ListObject ' ???
    Dim IDColumn, IDCurrent, iCount As Long ' ???

    
    ' Your preceding code...
    

    Dim sc As Long: sc = IDColumn.Index ' ???
    
    Dim srg As Range, scrg As Range, sFirstRow As Long, drg As Range
    Dim i As Long, rCount As Long
    
    For i = 0 To iCount ' ???
        
        ' It is assumed that the source data is sorted by column 'sc'
        ' i.e. the matches are in consecutive rows!
        
        Set srg = DBTable2(i).DataBodyRange
        Set scrg = srg.Columns(sc)
        rCount = Application.CountIf(scrg, IDCurrent)
        
        If rCount > 0 Then
            sFirstRow = Application.Match(IDCurrent, scrg, 0)
            Set srg = srg.Rows(sFirstRow).Resize(rCount)
            Set drg = InputTable2(i).DataBodyRange.Resize(rCount)
            drg.Value = srg.Value
            drg.Columns(DST_FORMULA_COLUMN_INDEX).FormulaR1C1 = DST_FORMULA_R1C1
        End If
                
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work. Initially, rCount was always 0, so I replaced it with my original RecordRows, which got me into the if statement. However, it did not copy any data across. for drg I saw that InputTable2(i).DataBodyRange.Resize(rCount) was not set, but couldn't see any value for srg.

Comment: If you could share the whole code and the screenshots of your tables (the before and after for the destination table), it would surely be a simple fix.